# IWindsorContainer does not contain a definition for 'GetService'

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, castle

I updated an old Castle.Windsor dll to the new NuGet one...

Actually I heve the folowing error:

> 'Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetService' and no extension method 'GetService' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

this is my code:

```
/// <summary>
/// IoC Abstraction
/// </summary>
public class ServiceLocator : IServiceLocator
{
    private IWindsorContainer _container;

    private ServiceLocator(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    private static IServiceLocator _current;

    public static IServiceLocator Current
    {
        get { return _current; }
        set { _current = value; }
    }

    public static void Register(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _current = new ServiceLocator(container);
    }

    public T GetInstance<T>()
    {
        return (T)_container.GetService(typeof(T));
    }

    public object GetInstance(Type t)
    {
        return _container.GetService(t);
    }

    public T GetService<T>()
    {
        return (T)_container.GetService(typeof(T));
    }

    public object GetService(Type t)
    {
        return _container.GetService(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your IoC abstraction is very leaky. Read [this article](http://kozmic.net/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor/) to see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Resolve](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Windsor-READONLY/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/Windsor/IWindsorContainer.cs#L176) method overloads:

```
public T GetInstance<T>()
{
    return _container.Resolve<T>();
}

public object GetInstance(Type t)
{
    return _container.Resolve(t);
}
```